# Info about this old riveting gun from West Germany?

Tags: tools, hand-tools, identify-a-tool, rivets, pop-rivets

Found a cute hand tool in a shed. Reverse image search suggests it's a riveting gun. One side says "Intern(i)et W. Germany", the other says "NZ-3". I'm not usually into riveting, however the name, "Internet" (or perhaps "Interniet"?), is intriguing and funny.

Does anyone have some context on the tool or the company that made it? Is it named Internet or Interniet? Why this name?

Photos (see my gallery on Google Drive for more: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-RViCp2E-ZEISgmGOOOtA6TBc-gEKmxd?usp=sharing):

[image: one angle]

[image: another angle]

[image: final angle]

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that ["Niet" is "rivet" in German](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Niet).

So it's Interniet, not Internet. User [crip659](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/128401/crip659) also managed to find some info on [the company](https://www.northdata.com/Interniet+-+Werkzeuge+Horst+Hinterth%C3%BCr,+Wuppertal/HRA+15584).

Answer (score 1):

Pretty standard-looking pop-riveting tool.

Looks to be a nice design with 4 sizes of collet and 3 places to not lose the ones not in use.

Comment: Mine also had plastic handles with a set of clips for the 4 hole wrench.

Comment: By that standard [mine](https://imgur.com/a/RTABksi) is pretty nice too!  Except I know mine is a POS I got at a dollar store. :)  Where OP's brand is cast into it, mine has an empty rectangular inset designating where a sticker might be placed, if anyone wanted to associate their brand with it. :)